# Codeigniter foreach . can't return values

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a code Like this

```
  function deletes2()
 {

   foreach ($_POST['selector'] as $id) 
   {
     $this->retailer_model->deletes($id);
   }

 }
```

Now i want to echo message like

```
echo"success"; or "error"
```

How can i do this??

Comment: What will be condition??? for success and error..

Comment: return something from your function to check then check in foreach

Comment: All the provided answers are fine, I'll just use a single line for it : ` return $status =='success' ? 'success' : 'failure';  -  makes it a bit easier to read instead of multiline ifs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to return flag to check from function like

```
function deletes($id) {
  // your queries
  if query run suceess.
    return true
  else
    return false;
}
```

then check in foreach

```
foreach ($_POST['selector'] as $id){
      $return = $this->retailer_model->deletes($id);
      if($return) {
        echo "success";
      } 
      else {
        echo "error";
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per assumption. here will be condition:

```
function deletes2() {
   $status = false;
   foreach ($_POST['selector'] as $id){
      $this->retailer_model->deletes($id);
      $status = true;
   }
   if($status) {
       return "success";
   } else {
       return "error";
   }
}
```

If your `foreach` loop will execute then it will return success else will return error. Hope so you are finding such condition.

cheers.